# Composer installer not working with Windows10

Tags: composer-php, windows-10

I am working on a web development project using laravel . I switched from Win8 to Win10 . But there is a problem, composer windows installer is not working(means the installer version is not supported for win10) on windows10 . So I get stucked . I tried(getcomposer.com sites ) windows manual installation procedure . But can not get it . Now what can i do?

Comment: What have you tried, what kind of error message do you get, what do you mean with **not working**? In it's current state this question really bad.

Comment: @Cyclone i updated . Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use your browser to download the latest PHAR: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
2. Drop it into your PHP folder and run: `php composer.phar -V`.
3. If you need a batch shortcut:

   ```
    fullpath_PHP_folder>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
   ```

   and from there on just `composer.bat`...

Comment: My guess would be that he haven't even installed php on the system =)

Comment: Yes, that's possible too :)

Comment: @JensA.Koch thank you very much . It worked for me. Hope here  people be more like you .

Comment: @avijitbhattacharjee during the upgrade to Windows 10 it's quite likely that PHP disappeared from your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes i installed xampp after Windows 10 installation :)

Comment: Actually when i am downloading composer-setup.exe from windows10 the file size is 4kb . but actual file size is 660 kb . so this is the problem.

Comment: I can' explain why that happens. May try a direct download from Github: https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/releases/download/v3.0/Composer-Setup.3.0.exe

Answer (score 0):

Actually when i download composer-setup.exe from windows 10 . The file size is 40 kb but actuall size is 640kb . This is the cause of the error.